# Keyboard flickers and screen jumps when using SecureField and TextField together in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, debugging, swiftui, ios17

This works

```
struct TestView: View {
    @State private var email = ""
    @State private var password = ""

    var body: some View {
 
            VStack{
                TextField("Enter your email", text: $email)
                    .font(.subheadline)
                    .padding(12)
                    .background(Color(.systemGray6))
                    .cornerRadius(10)
                    .padding(.horizontal, 24)
                
                TextField("Enter your password", text: $password)
                    .font(.subheadline)
                    .padding(12)
                    .background(Color(.systemGray6))
                    .cornerRadius(10)
                    .padding(.horizontal, 24)
            }

        }
    }
```

[TextFields only](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bvjVQ.gif)

This glitches, causing the screen and keyboard to flicker/jump

```
 struct TestView: View {
    @State private var email = ""
    @State private var password = ""

    var body: some View {
 
            VStack{
                TextField("Enter your email", text: $email)
                    .font(.subheadline)
                    .padding(12)
                    .background(Color(.systemGray6))
                    .cornerRadius(10)
                    .padding(.horizontal, 24)
                
                SecureField("Enter your password", text: $password)
                    .font(.subheadline)
                    .padding(12)
                    .background(Color(.systemGray6))
                    .cornerRadius(10)
                    .padding(.horizontal, 24)
            }

        }
    }
```

[TextField + SecureField](https://i.stack.imgur.com/teXua.gif)

I am using iOS17. I have tried on both simulated and physical (iPhone 13 Pro Max) devices. It is more noticeable on the physical device, however I still notice it on the simulator. Not sure if it is something I am doing wrong, or if this is a bug.

Comment: I only see it when switching between the two fields, which I think is normal (it seems to be caused by the automatic keyboard avoidance trying to "scroll" your views).

Comment: could not replicate your issue. All works well for me in my tests, on MacOS 14.2, Xcode 15.1, tested on real ios 17 devices (not Previews).
 It could be different on older systems. Do you have your `TestView` inside some other complex view,
 eg a TabView, or sheet ...?

Comment: I see some autolayout warnings in the console when the glitch occurs, similar to the ones reported in [SwiftUI TextFields on vanilla brand new project giving errors \[LayoutConstraints\]. How to fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76117124/swiftui-textfields-on-vanilla-brand-new-project-giving-errors-layoutconstraints). Might be a SwiftUI bug.

Comment: It's a bug. I've noticed this across multiple apps I've been working on. It was introduced in iOS 17. The issue seems to be only with the SecureField.

Comment: Since this ranks high on Google and seems unsolved: I noticed the same issue on a react site I'm building. This seems to be widespread, seemingly caused by iOS, there are bug reports for many frameworks, e.g. react-native https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/39411 and flutter https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/134723 but they all agree it must be lying deeper. There is a month old post on Apple's dev forum, but it has gotten very little attention: https://forums.developer.apple.com/forums/thread/744285